# Is the use of std::vector<bool> objects in C++ acceptable, or should I use an alternative?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, boolean, bitset

I'm working with a user-defined quantity of bits (I'm holding a three-dimensional array of bits, so the size increases cubically - assume no less then 512 bits), and need to flip them each individually.  Right now, just on a computer, I'm using the `bool` type, since memory isn't an issue.  I do plan to move the code to a microcontroller in the future, and so processing power and memory requirements may be an issue.  Right now though, I just want speed.

I then found the `std::bitset` object from the [C++ STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), but I can't define a bitset's size at runtime.  I then found that the `std::vector<bool>` has a special initializer to store them as bits (instead of entire bytes, or 4 bytes) but then found [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28C++%29#Specialization_for_bool) in Wikipedia:

> The Standard Library defines a specialization of the `vector` template
> for `bool`. The description of this specialization indicates that the
> implementation should pack the elements so that every `bool` only uses
> *one bit* of memory. This is widely considered a mistake. [...] There is a general consensus among the C++ Standard Committee and the Library Working Group that `vector<bool>` should be deprecated and subsequently removed from the standard library, while the functionality will be reintroduced under a different name.

Now, you can probably see my want for using a `vector<bool>` object, but after reading that, I'm considering using something else.  The only problem is that I'm not sure *what* to use.  I was curious though why they state that the functionality *should* be re-introduced (albeit under a different name).

So, my question is, would the use of `vector<bool>` objects be acceptable (being that they are a part of the STL)?  Are they a part of the C++ standard?

If their use is not acceptable, is there an acceptable, alternative solution (outside me defining a special container myself)?  I have a few ideas myself, but I'm just curious if anyone has a better solution.  Also, I would like to avoid using large libraries (again, I want to eventually port this code to a microcontroller).

Comment: What are the problems of just using for example `vec[bit>>3] |= (1<<(bit&7));` with an `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: Related:  Howard Hinnant's blog article [On `vector<bool>`](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool)  - terrible name for a useful data structure.  With appropriate specializations for `std::find`, `std::count`, and so on, a standard library can even expose fast system-specific optimizations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `vector<bool>`, except that it isn't equivalent to a `vector<T>` were T is the integer type equivalent to bool. This only shows in performance (CPUs only access bytes at a time, where in a `vector<bool>` every element is stored in one bit) and memory access (a reference to a first element of a `vector<bool>` is not equivalent to an array like with any other `vector<T>`.

It is part of the Standard, unfortunately: see section `23.3.7` (C++0x FDIS).

Comment: vector<bool> is optimized for space not speed. Also it does not confirm to container semantics exactly like the vector<T> does.

Answer (score 30):

[In "Effective STL," Item 18](http://books.google.com/books?id=RPnWe6QKnCcC&pg=PT93&lpg=PT93&dq=meyers%20avoid%20vector%20bool&source=bl&ots=injzzXkmZh&sig=BvHAPL78hD4yYHAFLpRbqyWORUM&hl=en&ei=KocoTtC6HOXa0QGYmM3MCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), Scott Meyers recommended: "Avoid using vector< bool >.":

> As an STL container, there are really only two things wrong with
>   vector< bool >. First, it's not an STL container. Second, it doesn't
>   hold bools. Other than that, there's not much to object to.

Answer (score 14):

The critique is that `vector<bool>` is the only standard container that doesn't **fully** conform to the standard's container requirements. That's a bit of a surprise.

Another point is that `vector<bool>` forces a space optimization on everyone (by storing bits), when perhaps some users would have preferred a speed optimization.

Other than that, the major deviation is that the container cannot return a reference to its members, because it doesn't store any bools. That will make the odd standard library algorithm fail to compile for `vector<bool>`.

If you can live with that, and it fits **your** needs for everything else, it is quite ok to use it.

Answer (score 11):

There is [boost.dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) which is nearly identical to std::bitset, except that its size is given at runtime. If you're not interested in boost dependency, its source code (which is entirely contained in its header file) could at least give more ideas on how such container could be written.

Comment: thank you for your response, I changed my question to more accurately reflect why I chose 512 (the grid *I'm working with* is 8x8x8, but it can be defined as any size, and so the number of elements [and thus memory requirements] increase cubically).

Comment: @Breakthrough Nevermind my note on 512, but is there any sort of internal structure to the data in that potentially large 3D array? Perhaps there are other data structures that could make use of that, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree and friends?

Comment: +1, and there is nothing wrong with your answer, and I really appreciate those alternate data types, but @rubenvb posted an answer that is more fitting to what I was looking for.  I don't think trees are the way to go in this case, since I'm not performing any binary searches whatsoever.  I do, however, need access to any element in this array nearly instantly in no particular order...

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with correct usage of `vector<bool>`, just like there's nothing wrong with `auto_ptr`- as long as you know the drawbacks and the surprises before going on.

Comment: Indeed.  If `vector<bool>` works for you, use it.  It's part of the standard.  If used safely, the worst that will happen when the specialization is removed in the future is not that your code will break, but that it will suddenly use a lot more RAM.

Comment: Do not use [`auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr). It was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be [BitMagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/index.html) although I'm not sure it works on any other architecture than x86(it's heavily optimized using SIMD).