# std::vector's push_back does not add the supplied value

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have the following function

```
std::vector<bool> buildBoolList(node* n)
{
    std::vector<bool> boolList;
    for(int i = 0; i < n->next.size(); i++)
    {
        int ival = atoi(n->next[i]->val.c_str());
        bool b = !!ival;
        boolList.push_back(b);
    }
    return boolList;
}
```

However every time I run my code boolList is always returned with a size of 0. I've run the debugger to ensure that atoi is returning a valid numeric and I've also ensured that b becomes the appropriate boolean value, however I can't seem to figure out why boolList is not populated.

Comment: what do you mean whit bool b = !!ival;   I mean using '!' twice ? and on an int value ?

Comment: @Engine Looks like a mad way to cast the value to `bool`. :)

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example of what's inside `n`? does it contain an array of strings? What's their value?

Comment: @Engine that's the easy way of convert integer to bool.

Comment: You should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using or just a modified snippet? Are you saying `boolList` contains some elements in the scope of the function, bu then, upon return you get an empty vector?

Comment: It is the exact code, the !! is a tip I found to ensure that your boolean value is either 0 or 1. One of the many solutions I tried.

Comment: @DamonSwayn I'd avoid sites that have tips like that.  The way to convert an integer to a `bool` is to use one of the comparison operators, e.g. `ival != 0` (or whatever condition you want).

Comment: Oh look, an [SSCCE](http://ideone.com/YDp1WM). So, it turns out there is no problem with pushing `bool` values into a vector of `bool`.

Comment: Never use vector of bools, its a lie, Ref.- **Scott Meyers's Item 18**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector<bool>` has been a kind of experiment by the C++ committee. It is actually a template specialization that stores the bool values tightly packed in memory: one bit per value.

And since you cannot have a reference to a bit, so you might be seeing the size as 0. 
 [Why vector<bool>::reference doesn't return reference to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool)

There's nothing wrong with `vector<bool>`, except that it isn't equivalent to a vector were T is the integer type equivalent to bool. This only shows in performance (CPUs only access bytes at a time, where in a `vector<bool>` every element is stored in one bit) and memory access (a reference to a first element of a vector is not equivalent to an array like with any other `vector<T>`. It is part of the Standard, unfortunately: see section 23.3.7 (C++0x FDIS)

Comment: That may be good advice, but I don't think it has relevance to this particular problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399417/why-vectorboolreference-doesnt-return-reference-to-bool

Comment: Interesting, I'm not quite sure I understand "it is not an STL container" though.

Comment: @DamonSwayn :I have modified my comments above, plz refer to the existing stackoverflow thread

Comment: @Saby What does the fact that its `operator[]` doesn't return a `bool&` have to do with the results of `size()`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with vector<bool>, except that it isn't equivalent to a vector<T> were T is the integer type equivalent to bool. This only shows in performance (CPUs only access bytes at a time, where in a vector<bool> every element is stored in one bit) and memory access (a reference to a first element of a vector<bool> is not equivalent to an array like with any other vector<T>.

It is part of the Standard, unfortunately: see section 23.3.7 (C++0x FDIS).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al

Comment: Interesting, looks like I'll have to rejigger my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Saby I think your last comment hits it on the head.  There's nothing wrong with `std::vector<bool>` per se, but it _doesn't_ implement the interface `std::vector` fully, which means that it is misnamed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n->next.size(); i++)
{
    int ival = atoi(n->next[i]->val.c_str());
```

I am almost certain you meant something along the lines of:

```
for(node* i = n; i->next != NULL; i=i->next)
{
    int ival = atoi(i->val.c_str());
```

Comment: next is a vector variable containing a list of children to the parent node, a node can have a variable number of children, so that's not what I meant.

Comment: I would have thought like Ofir, too. You should either explain why that code is there - what it has to do with your problem - or trim the example down to something more straight forward. If `std::vector<bool>::push_back` doesn't work, then `std::vector<bool> buildBoolList()
{
    std::vector<bool> boolList;
    boolList.push_back(true);
    return boolList;
}` would be sufficient.