# convert vector<bool> to decimal (as string)

Tags: c++

With this function we can easily convert vector to decimal (integer):

```
vector<bool> A = {0, 1, 1, 1,0,1}; # A size will change during run time
long int integer = 0, n = 0;

    for (auto i : A)
    {
        if (i)
        {
            integer += pow(2, n);
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
```

But if the vector has more than 64 elements the results will be unpredictable.

How can we do write similar function but returning string instead?

Comment: Considering you use `int`, which is a signed *32-bit* type on all modern (non-embedded) platforms, you run into trouble already at a size of 32 elements. You might want to check out [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: `long int` should fix it?

Comment: Only on platforms where `long int` is 64 bits, which is not all (the Visual C++ compiler still have 32-bit `long`, even on 64-bit systems).

Comment: You might want to see  Boost Multiprecision instead of returning a string.

Comment: If I use std::bitset, I will have 64 bit limitation. Even with to_ullong;

Comment: @user1436187 `std::bitset` is limited to 64 bits only if you want to get a single integer containing all bits. It *do* have [a function to get a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) though.

Comment: If your number exceeds 64 bits, and you want to make a decimal number representation, you will probably have to use some form of "large integer math" - using strings, you can write math that does add and multiply by two quite easily [actually multiply by two is the same as add number to itself, if you want to reduce the amount of code]. Or you can use a multiprecision library - boost, Gnu MP and several others are in existence - that will teach you less but make for less work in all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, using `std::bitset` is a better option for representing a binary number of any fixed length (for dynamic length, as in your case, see `boost::dynamic_bitset`). [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al) explains some reasons for why not using `std::vector<bool>`.

Your problem pretty much summarizes to implementing a BigNum class. Just like you did in your approach, you first need to convert your value from binary to decimal (but now precision above 64 bits is needed). Once the BigNum is constructed, converting it to a string is trivial. I implemented the algorithm you requested by simply modifying a `BigNum` class that I made some time ago.

To print the binary number, the following lines should suffice.

```
/*Creates a 90-digit binary number with all bits set.*/
std::vector<bool> A(90, 1);
/*Prints its decimal reprsentation*/
cout << longBinaryToDecimalAsString(A);
```

**As for the implementation:**

```
#ifndef BIG_NUM_H
#define BIG_NUM_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

class BigNum {

public:

    BigNum(){values.push_back(0);}

    BigNum(std::uint64_t val){
        if (val == 0)
            values.assign(1, 0);
        else{
            while (val > 0){
                values.push_back(val % 10);
                val /= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    BigNum &operator+=(BigNum &rhs)
    {
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> *lowAddend, *bigAddend;
        /*If right value is larger, ‘values’ vector will always grow*/
        if (rhs.values.size() > values.size()){
            values.resize(rhs.values.size(), 0);
            lowAddend = &values;
            bigAddend = &rhs.values;
        }
        else{
            values.push_back(0);
            bigAddend = &values;
            lowAddend = &rhs.values;
        }

        std::uint8_t carry = 0;
        size_t i = 0;
        /*First we sum lower part*/
        for (; i < lowAddend->size(); ++i){
            std::uint8_t sum = values[i] + rhs.values[i] + carry;
            values[i] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        /*Now we copy the remaining part*/
        for (; i < bigAddend->size(); ++i){
            /*For 10 10, sum will be 18, at most*/
            std::uint8_t sum = (*bigAddend)[i] + carry;
            values[i] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        this->trimFrontalZeros();
        return *this;
    }
    BigNum &operator*=(BigNum &rhs)
    {
        /*Case when one of the operands is Zero*/
        if (this->isZero())
            return *this;
        else if (rhs.isZero()){
            values.assign(1, 0);    
            return *this;
        }

        size_t maxLen = values.size() + rhs.values.size();
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> product(maxLen);

        size_t lowSize, bigSize;
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> *multiplier, *multiplicand;

        /*The iteration process for the multiplicaiton is developed as the multiplier (A in A*B)
        as the one with more digits.*/
        if (values.size() > rhs.values.size()){
            multiplier = &values;
            multiplicand = &rhs.values;
            bigSize = values.size();
            lowSize = rhs.values.size();
        }
        else{
            multiplier = &rhs.values;
            multiplicand = &values;
            bigSize = rhs.values.size();
            lowSize = values.size();
        }

        /*Implemented as 'values x rhs.values' */
        std::uint8_t carry = 0;
        for (size_t n = 0; n < maxLen; ++n){

            size_t numIters;
            if (maxLen - n - 1< lowSize) numIters = maxLen - n - 1;
            else                         numIters = std::min(n + 1, lowSize);

            std::uint64_t sum = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < numIters; ++i){
                size_t indBelow = i + n + 1 - std::min(n + 1, lowSize);
                size_t indAbove = std::min(n + 1, lowSize) - 1 - i;
                std::uint8_t be = (*multiplier)[indBelow];
                std::uint8_t ab = (*multiplicand)[indAbove];
                sum += be*ab;
            }
            sum += carry;
            product[n] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        values.assign(product.begin(), product.end());
        this->trimFrontalZeros();
        return *this;
    }

    std::string toString(){
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::copy(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ""));
        return ss.str();
    }

private:

    bool isAbsOne() {return values.size() == 1 && values[0] == 1;}
    bool isZero()   {return values.size() == 1 && values[0] == 0;}
    void trimFrontalZeros(){
        size_t newSize = values.size();
        auto it = values.rbegin();
        while (it != values.rend() && *it == 0){
            ++it;
            --newSize;
        }
        values.resize(newSize);
    }

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> values;
};

std::string longBinaryToDecimalAsString(std::vector<bool> &longBinary){

    BigNum big;
    std::uint64_t n = 0;
    for (bool bit : longBinary){
        if (bit){
            if (n > 63){
                BigNum aux(1);          
                for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < n / 32; ++i){
                    aux *= BigNum(1ULL << 32);
                }
                aux *= BigNum(1ULL << (n % 32));
                big += aux;
            }
            else{
                big += BigNum(1ULL << n);
            }
        }
        ++n;
    }
    return big.toString();
}

#endif
```

Please do note this is a very reduced version of a `BigNum` class. Using it for purposes other than the one of this question may output undesired results. For example, as is, it does not take into account negative numbers for the `+` and `*` operations.

Comment: Don't reinvent your [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum)s. Use an existing bignum library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: That is true enough! There are many existing good multiprecision libraries out there. If you want something stable and efficient, you should check them. The implementation I posted simply depicts a way of doing it. If you are going to use it for "non-serious" purposes (as in a commercial product), it should be ok :).