# Indexing std::vector<bool> works with true values, but does not work with false values

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to run a simple program in C++ in which there are two vectors - one is a `std::vector<int>` and the other is a `std::vector<bool>` of equal length. The value of the boolean vector at an index decides whether the value of the integer vector will be printed or not. Here is a copy of the program I am trying to run:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<bool> b(true, arr.size());

    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++){
        if(b[i])
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program runs as expected. But there is an Address Boundary Error encountered when I change the values from `true` to `false` in the std::vector initialization line. Precisely, the error is:

```
fish: Job 1, './test_vector_bool' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I am already aware of some of the major pitfalls of using `vector<bool>` from these threads:

- [Is the use of std::vector objects in C++ acceptable, or should I use an alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781985/is-the-use-of-stdvectorbool-objects-in-c-acceptable-or-should-i-use-an-al)
- [Is vector < bool > really so bad?](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/57052)

What I gathered from these threads is we should not be using reference for `vector<bool>` in cpp. But all I need to know is why is the vector with `true` working and initialization with `false` failing?

Comment: `b(true, arr.size())` - > `b(arr.size(), true)` The size comes before the default value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a vector in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906545/how-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `vector<bool> b(true, arr.size());` will create a vector, with `1` element, of value `arr.size()`. Thus, the loop will get out of bounds.

It's crucial to remember that when we construct a container this way, we say: *"How much of what"*.

In this case: *"We need `arr.size()` elements with value `true`"*:

```
vector<bool> b(arr.size(), true);
```

*For more information, you may want to check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) on vector constructors, the third one in particular, "fill constructor".*

Comment: I feel so stupid to have messed this up. Once in a *fool* moon, we do forget basic things. I came back to delete this question, but since you took the pain to answer this stupid question I am leaving it as it is marking your answer as solution.

Comment: @DeeptenduSantra happens to the best of us! It's all good, you should feel free to manage the post as you consider it should be managed. Best of luck to you!

Comment: I completely missed the fact because there should be some out of bounds error when I run the code in the question, the result is 1 2 3 4 5. It should return boundary error in that case too.

Comment: You might want to explain the (not shown) line `vector<bool> b(false, arr.size());` instead of (or in addition to) `vector<bool> b(true, arr.size());`, as the former is what triggered the SIGSEGV signal.

Comment: @rawrex *"You should feel free to manage the post as you consider it should be managed."* -- nice sentiment, but unfortunately not realistic. A user cannot delete their own question if it has an answer with upvotes.

Comment: @JaMiT *"A user cannot delete their own question if it has an answer with upvotes"* - was not aware of that. Thanks! Will consider taking actions based on the fresh input shortly.